# How do I get the first jpg/png image url from an array of image urls?

Tags: ruby

I have a function called `images` that returns an array of image urls from a remote website. I use it like this:

```
return page.description || page.images[0]
```

When the `description` of `page` is absent, it returns the first image url in the array. I want to get the first image with `jpg` or `png` extension rather than whatever. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
images = ['http://example.com/a.html', 'http://example.com/image.jpg', 'http://example.com/image.png']
images.find { |url| url =~ /\.(jpg|png)$/i }
# => "http://example.com/image.jpg"
images.find { |url| url.downcase.end_with?('.jpg', '.png') }
# => "http://example.com/image.jpg"
```

Comment: thank you @falsetru it works, there is no problem if i downcase the url ?

Comment: @medBo, url itself is not downcased.

Comment: @medBo, I provided two solution in the answer: one that use regular expression, and the other that use String methods.

Comment: i tested just the first one, but no idea what is the best/fast

Comment: can i also check that image have width > 50px ?

Comment: @medBo, To check the width, you should fetch the iamges, open it with image processing library.